# Javascript Kinetic Text Animation alignment

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I am trying to animate text in a canvas using Kinetic js

Canvas size 940 x 600

Animations are x and y

I can't seem to get the positioning right, I would like the vertical to start and finish at the top and the horizontal to start and finish on the left side.

Currently they are moving the right direction, but they start and finish out side of the canvas.

This may have something to do with the set amplitude, but i'm not that great at js coding yet to know whats wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/eev8u/3/

```
<script defer="defer">
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'horandvert',
    width: 940,
    height: 600
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var hbox = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 50,
    y: 240,
    fontSize: 38,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    text: 'Horizontal',
    fill: '#317d37',
    padding: 0,
  });

  var vbox = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 330,
    y: 50,
    fontSize: 38,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    text: 'Vertical',
    fill: '#317d37',
    padding: 0,
  });

  layer.add(hbox);
  layer.add(vbox);
  stage.add(layer);

  var amplitude = 400;
  var period = 3000;

  var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
  hbox.setX (amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 1 * Math.PI / period)); 
  vbox.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 1 * Math.PI / period));
  }, layer);

  anim.start();      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to adjust the alignment in your sine wave animation**

This is what a sine wave looks like

[image]

Notice it always generates a number from +1 to -1.

Since your words follow the sine values...

- Your words are go offscreen when the sine is generating negative numbers.
- Your words come back onscreen when sine is generating positive numbers.

**amplitude:**

- Is the “swing” in sine:
- Greater amplitude == greater movement (left-right or up-down)

**period:**

- Is the regulator of speed.
- It is the denominator in frames per second (frames/period).
- Greater period == slower speed

So...to keep your words swinging onscreen, just add Amplitude to your X/Y values.

This adjusts the sine value to always be 0+.

Here is a simplified version of your animation that moves in a sine wave that’s always onscreen:

```
// amplitude is how much "swing" is in your words
var amplitude = 100;

// period adjusts the framerate of your animation
var period = 1000;

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    hbox.setX (amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time/period)+amplitude); 
    vbox.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time/period)+amplitude);
}, layer);
```

Here is full code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wazpx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){


var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var hbox = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 50,
  y: 240,
  fontSize: 38,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  text: 'Horizontal',
  fill: '#317d37',
  padding: 0,
});

var vbox = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 240,
  y: 50,
  fontSize: 38,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  text: 'Vertical',
  fill: '#317d37',
  padding: 0,
});

layer.add(hbox);
layer.add(vbox);

// amplitude is how much "swing" is in your words
// greater amplitude == greater swing
var amplitude = 100;

// period adjusts the framerate of your animation
// greater period == slower fps and therefore slower animation
var period = 1000;

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    hbox.setX (amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time/period)+amplitude); 
    vbox.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time/period)+amplitude);
}, layer);

anim.start();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```